# Automatic set-up, the network can bus with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, interface

I want to set-up the network of the CAN bus automatically with Ubuntu 20.04.

For other distributions, it is done like this in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
allow-hotplug can0
iface can0 can static
    bitrate 500000
```

But I did not find this path etc/network/interfaces .
An

Answer (score 2):

Create a file `/etc/systemd/network/80-can.network` with the following contents:

```
[Match]
Name=can*

[CAN]
BitRate=500K
```

Then enable and start `systemd-networkd`:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

You should now see the CAN network in `ifconfig`:

```
$ ifconfig 
can0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 16
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 10  (UNSPEC)
        ...
```

Source: https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2021/07/automatically-bring-up-a-socketcan-interface-on-boot/

Answer (score 0):

I think that Ubuntu 20 is not using `/etc/network/interfaces` but using `/etc/netplan`.

Please modify or create `/etc/netplan/XXXXXX.yaml` and edit it.

Comment: Any pointers as to how the netplan file for CAN looks like?